Trying to show the identity $c(\text{End}(E)) = c(E^* \otimes E) = c(E^*) \cdot c(E)$
Given a vector bundle $E \to M$ I'm trying to derive the identity
$$
c_2(\text{End}(E))=\text{rk}(E)(2c_2(E)-c_1(E)^2) + c_1(E)^2
$$
but I'm facing some issues with the individual Chern classes not playing nicely with tensor products. For the total Chern class we have
$$
c(\text{End}(E)) = c(E^* \otimes E) = c(E^*) \cdot c(E)
$$
but I didn't find this helpful computing the second chern class. Any tips on what we can do here?

You should remember the definition : .$ch(E)= rk(E)+c_1(E)+{1\over 2}(c_1^2(E)-2c_2(E))$

No, $c(E\oplus F) = c(E)c(F)$, so your equation is incorrect. You need Chern character to play with the tensor product. However, avoiding that, the best thing to do is to use the splitting principle and write $E=L_1\oplus\dots\oplus L_m$, so
$$E^*\otimes E =(L_1\oplus\dots\oplus L_m)\otimes(L_1^*\oplus\dots\oplus L_m^*) = \bigoplus_{i,j} L_i\otimes L_j^*.$$
Writing $c_1(L_i) = \lambda_i$, we therefore have
$$c(E^*\otimes E) = \prod_{i,j} (1+\lambda_i-\lambda_j).$$
As I suggested in this post, it is less confusing to write out the general case $c(E\otimes F)$ and then specialize to $F=E^*$ at the end.
So, with $c(F)=\prod (1+\mu_j)$, $\text{rk}(E)=m$ and $\text{rk}(F)=n$, we will have
$$c(E\otimes F) = \prod_{i,j} (1+\lambda_i+\mu_j),$$
and so, with careful counting, we arrive (I think) at
$$c_1(E\otimes F) = nc_1(E) + mc_1(F)$$
and
\begin{multline*}
c_2(E\otimes F) = \textstyle\binom n2 (c_1^2(E)-2c_2(E))+n^2c_2(E) + \textstyle\binom m2 (c_1^2(F)-2c_2(F)) \\ + m^2c_2(F)+(mn-1)c_1(E)c_1(F).
\end{multline*}
(Note that $c_1(E)=\sum\lambda_i$ and $c_2(E)=\sum_{i<j}\lambda_i\lambda_j$, so $\sum\limits_{i,j} \lambda_i\lambda_j = \sum\lambda_i^2 + \sum\limits_{i\ne j}\lambda_i\lambda_j$, and so $\sum\lambda_i^2=c_1^2(E)-2c_2(E)$.) Therefore, since $c_1(E^*)=-c_1(E)$ and $c_2(E^*)=c_2(E)$, we get
\begin{align*}
c_2(E\otimes E^*) &= 2\textstyle{\binom m2}(c_1(E)^2-2c_2(E))+2m^2c_2(E)-(m^2-1)c_1(E)^2 \\ &= (1-m)c_1(E)^2+2mc_2(E).
\end{align*}
Whew!
